# nicEdit toolbar buttons are partly visible

Tags: nicedit

Just top of the toolbar buttons images are visible. Where can be a problem?

```
$ ->
  ne = new nicEditor({iconsPath: '/assets/nicEditorIcons.gif'})
  ne.panelInstance('answer_comment')
```

[image: nicEdit toolbar problem]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Was some mysterious problem with cache in development stage. If you having this problem remove rails cache, restart server and hard-refresh browser.